# Movie control Package

Tags: java, quicktime

i have a simple Java off-line application that it has to show and control a movie ....

What is the package and classes that contain the methods that do such tasks?!

i expect the existence like the following methods :

1) void PlayMovie(); // to play the movie...

2) void PlayMovie(int Time); // to play the movie starting from a specific time...

3) void GoTo(int Time); // Go to play a specific time...

4) void Stop(); // Stop playing the movie...

5) int GetDuration(); // returns the movie lenght...

6) String GetCodek(); // returns the codek name...

And so ....

Is there a complete set to handel and control the movie like above?.... or i am just dreaming !

PLEASE NOTE THAT I AM ON A MAC OSX-10.6 (and not windows)
Thanks for any help

Comment: The other replies mention JMF.  Unfortunately besides being very old, JMF has been abandoned and the codecs and formats it supports have not been updated/expanded in a long time.  As a result of that, JMF will load a MOV recorded with my older Kodak camera (a DX 6490), yet fails to load a MOV produced from the next Kodak model (a DX 7590).  Note that both MOV types are 640x480 - nothing special.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [Java Media Framework API (JMF)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html)

You can find a simple example of a JMF utilisation on [snipplr](http://snipplr.com/view/1592/java--example-very-simple-player-jmf/)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the Java Media Framework. It has been around for many many years, and is pretty straight forward to use.

Check out the Wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework for information, or take a look on the Oracle site for plenty of examples.